# Search through XDocument for XElement with certain Attribute using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a XML document that looks like this:

```
<Window x:Name="winName" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="My Window" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="true">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <GroupBox x:Name="grBox" Header="Main Group Box" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
                <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <TabItem x:Name="mainTab" Header="Main Tab" />
                </TabControl>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want my code to find `XElement` TabItem with x:Name mainTab. This is how my code looks:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
XNamespace xaml = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from myElems in doc.Descendants(xmlns + "Window")
                               where myElems.Attribute(xaml + "Name").Value == "mainTab"
                               select myElems;
```

But this doesn't work, there are no results. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple problems.  You're telling `Descendants()` to look for an element with the local name `Window`, you should be telling it to look for the element with the local name `TabItem` (the item you actually want).

Second, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` if you ever have a `TabItem` that doesn't have an `x:Name` attribute; you'd be attempting to get the `Value` field on a null reference, so you should cast the return of `Attribute()` to a string and compare that.

Here's the working select:

```cs
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from myElems in doc.Descendants(xmlns + "TabItem")
                               where (string)myElems.Attribute(xaml + "Name") == "mainTab"
                               select myElems;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, master. You made my life better :)